# Remove both float64 values if found in either columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, notin

I'm trying to remove all rows if a non unique value is found example below:

```
    N1  N2
1   2   4
2   4   5
3   6   6
4   8   7
5   10  8
6   12  10
7   NaN 12
8   NaN 14
```

So in this instance the values I want is 2 5 7 and 14. Also one column is longer than the other and hence has to ignore NaN. I basically want to find repeating values and delete both from N1 and N2. This is what I tried:

`df[~df.N1.isin(['N2'])]`

Got some error. Thank you for your help.

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution:

```
>> df.stack().drop_duplicates(keep=False).unstack()

    N1    N2
1  2.0   NaN
2  NaN   5.0
4  NaN   7.0
8  NaN  14.0
```

As a list:

```
>> df.stack().drop_duplicates(keep=False).values.tolist()

[2.0, 5.0, 7.0, 14.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can be achieved:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = '''N1 N2
2 4
4 5
6 6
8 7
10 8
12 10
NaN 12
NaN 14'''

ss = StringIO(s)


df = pd.read_csv(ss, sep=r'\s+')

df = df.dropna()

df[~df.N1.isin(['N2'])]
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe out of the values that you have posted:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'N1':[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'N2':[4,5,6,7,8,10,12,14]})
```

Find the common values:

```
common = list(set(df['N1']) & set(df['N2']))
```

Exclude all the rows that either `N1` or `N2` has one of them:

```
df[(~df["N1"].isin(common)) | (~df["N2"].isin(common))]
```

**Update**

```
common = set(df['N1']) & set(df['N2'])
result = list(set(df['N2'])-common) + list(set(df['N1'])-common)
result = [x for x in result if x==x]
```

Comment: Forget the NaN bit all i want to do is find unique values from N1 and N2 and any repeat delete them all

Comment: the answert for the example is a list containing  2 5 7 and 14

Comment: Why not 8 as well?